# Get Page View Data from Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

Using the .NET/C# library from Application Insights, is there a way for me to retrieve Page View data?

Comment: What library, you mean the Application Insights SDK? Then no, that is not possible. It is only for sending data. For getting data you can use the [Rest API](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/overview)

Comment: Sweet! That works!

Comment: then @PeterBons should add that as an answer and get some internetpoints :D

Comment: @JohnGardner like that? :-P Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What library, you mean the Application Insights SDK? Then no, that is not possible. It is only for sending data. For getting data you can use the [Rest API](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/overview).

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use [Azure.Monitor.Query](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Azure.ResourceManager.Monitor_1.3.0/sdk/monitor/Azure.Monitor.Query) .NET library to fetch data from Application Insights API (Azure Monitor Logs). It have Logs and Metrics clients.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).