# Redirect Azure application insights Metrics to outside Azure framework

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I want to showcase Application Insights Metrics to my Portal Dashboard.

I checked Application Insights where i can share the dashboard with other users with in the Azure account.
Is there any way to share AI Metrics outside azure.

Edit per comments: I want to showcase the same graph generate by AI on my dashboard

Comment: Your question confuses me, are you looking for a way to display metrics (I assume with Matrics you mean metrics, correct me if I am wrong) on another users azure portal dashboard? Or do you want to expose the metrics data on some other portal dashboard that is not hosted in Azure?

Comment: Yes. I want to display Application Insights metrics on my website which are not hosted on azure. Azure might be provide any rest API link OR any code which can be integrated with my application.

Comment: See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392777/get-page-view-data-from-application-insights/45431360#45431360 for a link to the rest api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Page View Data from Application Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392777/get-page-view-data-from-application-insights)

Comment: https://dev.applicationinsights.io provide the Rest client to get the aggregated value but I want to showcase the same graph generate by AI on my dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Application Insights chart will allow you to add in Azure Dashboard & [sharing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-dashboards#share-dashboards) with users (not outside)

Application Insights - Analytics will allow you to write custom query & visualize chart. Then you can [pin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-using#pin-to-dashboard) it in dashboard & share with users (not outside)

For outside users, you are asking above functionality in your portal. To do that you have to use [Rest API](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/overview). This wont give the MS internal assets to your portal. You have to use [PowerBI](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Power-BI) & embed in your portal (Excel/AppInsights also available)

Use some third party chart library to display the JSON result as chart.