# Getting information of Azure app insights via RestAPI

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have deployed a web job to Azure and also have a request/response graphs associated with it (insight). I want to extract the graph information and display it on another web page (as an embedded graph). Please see the attached screenshot for my azure dashboard which have the graph.

Is there a RESTApi or any SDK available to get graph(app insight) from azure and display it in the web page? 
(hope this is not related to powerbi) 
[image]

Comment: I'm not  familar with  Azure App insights REST API, but this document may be helpful:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Page View Data from Application Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392777/get-page-view-data-from-application-insights)

Answer (score 0):

If you want get the requests and AverageResponseTime metrics We could use the [Monitor API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list) or [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor) to do that. I do a demo to get the Azure WebApp request metrics demo. Other supported metrics supported metrics please refer to [Azure Monitor Metrics List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftwebsites-excluding-functions).

**Preparetion:**

[Registry Azure Active Directory application and assign Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application)

Then we can get the tenantId,clientId,clientSecretKey

```
 var azureTenantId = "tenantId";
 var azureSecretKey = "clientSecretKey";
 var azureAppId = "clientId";
 var subscriptionId = "subscriptionId";
 var resourceGroup = "ResourceGroup";
 var webAppName = "webAppname";
 var serviceCreds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(azureTenantId, azureAppId, azureSecretKey).Result;
 var client = new MonitorClient(serviceCreds) {SubscriptionId = subscriptionId};
 var resourceUrl = $"subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{webAppName}";
 var result = client.Metrics.ListWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceUrl,metric: "Requests",interval:new TimeSpan(0,0,5,0),timespan: "2018-02-19T06:57:56Z/2018-02-20T07:57:56Z").Result;
```

[image]